# Problema consulta BD error near '+'

Tags: base-de-datos

no sé ya ver que me falla en la consulta... tengo lo siguiente:

```
USE [GCP]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[REPORTING_ADABAS_spDIFERENCIAS_CUADRE_TIPO]    Script Date: 9/11/2020 15:09:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPORTING_ADABAS_spDIFERENCIAS_CUADRE_TIPO]

    @empresa as tinyint,
    @fechaini as varchar(10),
    @fechafin as varchar(10),
    @liston as int=0

AS

set nocount on;
DECLARE @EmpresaFiltro int
DECLARE @nomempresa as varchar(100)


IF (@empresa=1 OR @empresa=2) SET @nomempresa = 'Main.'
ELSE IF @empresa=4 SET @nomempresa = 'Aumar.'
ELSE IF @empresa=9 SET @nomempresa = 'Avasa.'
ELSE IF @empresa=3 SET @nomempresa = 'Iberpistas.'
ELSE IF @empresa=11 SET @nomempresa = 'Iberpistas.'



--Asigno un filtro especifico por empresa para IberpistasCastellana para evitar cruce de información
IF(@empresa = 3) SET @EmpresaFiltro = 2
ELSE IF (@empresa = 11) SET @EmpresaFiltro = 11 

CREATE TABLE #tempCuadre(
    ID_LIQUIDACION int,NumLiq varchar(10),
    Estacion varchar(100), FechaDiaExplotacion datetime,
    inCuadre datetime2,finCuadre datetime2,
    NumVia varchar(10),
    recteor decimal(18,2),recteorev decimal(18,2),recont decimal(18,2),
    CodigoMotivo varchar(15),
    DifMotivo decimal(18,2), NumDif tinyint,
    LIQR_CODIGO varchar(10)
     
)

DECLARE @sSQL varchar(2000)
    SET @sSQL = 'INSERT INTO #tempCuadre(ID_LIQUIDACION,FechaDiaExplotacion,Estacion,inCuadre,finCuadre,recteorev,recteor,recont,NumLiq,NumVia,CodigoMotivo,DifMotivo,NumDif,liqr_codigo)
        SELECT ID_LIQUIDACION,Fecha,Estacion,horainicio,horafin,recteorev,recteor,recont,liqr_codigo,liqr_codvia,CodigoMotivo,DiferenciaMotivo,NumDif,liqr_codigo
        FROM (
            SELECT l.ID_LIQUIDACION,liqr_fecdiaex as Fecha ,liqr_codestac as Estacion
                , liqr_horainiac as horainicio, liqr_horafinac as horafin
                , (l.liqr_impptacn-m.Liqr_impfsdif)*0.01 as recteorev
                , LIQR_IMPTEOR*0.01 as recteor, liqr_impptacn*0.01 as recont
                , m.Liqr_impfsdif*0.01 as difinal
                , l.liqr_codigo, l.liqr_codvia,
                m.liqr_codmotdif as CodigoMotivo, m.Liqr_impfsdif*0.01 as DiferenciaMotivo, m.liqr_difcount as NumDif  
            FROM '+@nomempresa+'liquidaciones l 
                INNER JOIN '+@nomempresa+' +liq_dif m ON l.id_liquidacion = m.id_liquidacion and m.cnxarraycolumn = 1 and LIQR_CODMOTDIF <>''''''''
            WHERE l.liqr_tipliqui = ''''V'''' and (abs(l.liqr_impptacn-l.liqr_impteor) * 0.01)>='+cast(@liston as varchar)+' AND l.liqr_fecdiaex BETWEEN '''''+@fechaini+''''' And '''''+@fechafin+'''''
            )'
```

y me falla el inner join :

'+@nomempresa+' +liq_dif

llevo horas dándole vueltas, pero ya no sé que puede ser...

podéis ayudarme?

Comment: haz un print a la variable @sSQL para ver que valor tiene.

Comment: sorry no sé como hacer el print... :S donde lo pongo?

Comment: sobre la Base de datos hay 5 tablas que son: Empresax1.liq_dif , Empresax2.liq_dif ....

Comment: que dice el error completo? eliminemos comentarios.. arregla la pregunta, pone el error completo, aclara la base de datos...

Comment: @MontseMkd solamente toma la parte del IF donde defines la empresa y donde construyes la variable sSQL, luego ejecutalo como un query cualquiera, fuera del SP, ahi haces "print @sSQL".

Comment: asumo que es SQL Server por el "dbo" pero no esta de mas que indiques la versión que usas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error se origina por la concatenación de la variable @sSQL.

Cuando uses comillas simples internamente en el string, usa primero comillas dobles.

Ejemplo UPDATE tabla SET campo='abc123' WHERE condition;

```
@SQl = "UPDATE tabla SET campo_string=' " + @OTRA_VARIABLE + "' WHERE condition";
```

Por favor sustituye la última variable por:

```
DECLARE @sSQL varchar(2000)
SET @sSQL = "INSERT INTO #tempCuadre(ID_LIQUIDACION,FechaDiaExplotacion,Estacion,inCuadre,finCuadre,recteorev,recteor,recont,NumLiq,NumVia,CodigoMotivo,DifMotivo,NumDif,liqr_codigo)
    SELECT ID_LIQUIDACION,Fecha,Estacion,horainicio,horafin,recteorev,recteor,recont,liqr_codigo,liqr_codvia,CodigoMotivo,DiferenciaMotivo,NumDif,liqr_codigo
    FROM (
        SELECT l.ID_LIQUIDACION,liqr_fecdiaex as Fecha ,liqr_codestac as Estacion
            , liqr_horainiac as horainicio, liqr_horafinac as horafin
            , (l.liqr_impptacn-m.Liqr_impfsdif)*0.01 as recteorev
            , LIQR_IMPTEOR*0.01 as recteor, liqr_impptacn*0.01 as recont
            , m.Liqr_impfsdif*0.01 as difinal
            , l.liqr_codigo, l.liqr_codvia,
            m.liqr_codmotdif as CodigoMotivo, m.Liqr_impfsdif*0.01 as DiferenciaMotivo, m.liqr_difcount as NumDif  
        FROM "+@nomempresa+"liquidaciones l 
            INNER JOIN "+@nomempresa+" +liq_dif m ON l.id_liquidacion = m.id_liquidacion and m.cnxarraycolumn = 1 and LIQR_CODMOTDIF <>
            WHERE l.liqr_tipliqui = 'V' and (abs(l.liqr_impptacn-l.liqr_impteor) * 0.01)>="+cast(@liston as varchar)+ "AND l.liqr_fecdiaex BETWEEN "+@fechaini+ " And "+@fechafin+ ")"
```